# How to add event listener on folder in Electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm trying to detect changes in folder for example when I create/update something in specified folder, I need to see that in console of my electron app, so the question is how to show in console every changes in folder and when I click on any file, how to detect on which file I clicked, is it possible with electronjs/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

[this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/160/watch-files-and-directories-with-electron-framework) compares the `chokidar` module with the node.js builtins `fs.watch()` and `fs.watchFile()` and comes to the conclusion that `chokidar` is the way to go. So there's your alternatives for implementing this feature.

This does not handle clicking on files though (you mean in the file explorer, not in your app, right?) which is not possible afaik.